# Rails Unit Testing won't update database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I'm trying to run the following unit-test:

```
def test_passwordchange
    # check success
    assert_equal @longbob, Usuario.autenticar("longbob", "longtest")
    #change password
    @longbob.password = "nonbobpasswd"
    @longbob.password_confirmation = "nonbobpasswd"

    assert @longbob.save!
    #new password works
    assert_equal @longbob, Usuario.autenticar("longbob", "nonbobpasswd")
    #old pasword doesn't work anymore
    assert_nil   Usuario.autenticar("longbob", "longtest")
    #change back again
    @longbob.password = "longtest"
    @longbob.password_confirmation = "longtest"
    assert @longbob.save!
    assert_equal @longbob, Usuario.autenticar("longbob", "longtest")
    assert_nil   Usuario.autenticar("longbob", "nonbobpasswd")
  end
```

However, it throws error on the 1st line that contains "assert_equal" that says:

```
<#<Usuario ID: 1000003, login: "longbob", hashed_password: "078cf6ae2de80ed6c004c8c8576a5572e077a52c", salt: "1000", nombre: nil, apellido: nil, email: "lbob@mcbob.com", telefono: nil, tipo_usuario: nil, foto: nil, bol_activo: nil>> expected but was <nil>.
```

Here's my authenticate method:

```
def self.authenticate (login, pass)
    u=find(:first, :conditions=>["login = ?", login])
    return nil if u.nil?
    return u if Usuario.encrypt(pass, u.salt)==u.hashed_password
    nil
  end
```

Also, I defined the following:

```
def password=(pass)
    @password=pass
    self.salt = Usuario.random_string(10) if !self.salt?
    self.hashed_password = Usuario.encrypt(@password, self.salt)
  end
```

So, I guess that should update the hashed_password every time I reassigned something to "password"... right?

Whats happening?

Thx.

***UPDATE:*** I noticed that if I change:

> assert_equal @**longbob**,
>   Usuario.autenticar("longbob",
>   "nonbobpasswd")

to

> assert_equal @**longbob2**,
>   Usuario.autenticar("longbob",
>   "nonbobpasswd")

It passes that test, however it fails in the following line... Trowing the same error... What's up with that?

Comment: Is the `Usuario` a typing error for `User` or do you really use 2 different classes ? If so, could you please provide the source code of the 2 methods `authenticate`.

Comment: Was a type-o ... already fixed

Comment: Did you check if `@longbob.save` update the record ? You can add a test like `assert_nil Usuario.authenticate("longbob", "longtest")` after saving it.

Comment: You said if you change @longbob to @longbob2 on the test which fail the test passed, it's normal since @longbob2 isn't defined it's like replacing @longbob by nil.   When you said it fails in the following line, on which test assertion is it ? If it's on the assert_nil assertion then the problem is that your call to save does not update the record in the DB, if so you would suggest you to write another test which reflect this behaviour.

Comment: It doesn't answer the issue directly, but have you tried using the authlogic gem which takes care of all of this for you?

Comment: So, Adrien, what you're saying is I cannot test things that I need to save first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer after my comment, we find out that the problem is the call to `save` does not update the record in the database. I have suggested  you to write another test to see this behaviour and be able to fix it, the test you have writed start to be too long and in fact the bug does not have anything related to the authenticate mechanism.

Here is the test I would write :

```
def test_change_password_save
  old_hash = @longbob.hashed_password
  @longbob.password = "nonbobpasswd"
  @longbob.password_confirmation = "nonbobpasswd"
  @longbob.save
  assert_not_equal(old_hash, @longbox.reload.hashed_password)
end
```

If this test failed, I would suggest you to write another question in stackoverflow for this bug.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting a validation error.  Check the contents of `@longbob.errors`.

What happens if you split this into two separate statements? (Which is good practice anyway)

```
@longbob.password = @longbob.password_confirmation = "nonbobpasswd"
```

See, `#password_confirmation=` is actually a method, which might not return the value that was passed to it, depending on how the method was implemented.

Comment: Got the same error:
<#<Usuario ID: 1000003, login: "longbob", hashed_password: "078cf6ae2de80ed6c004c8c8576a5572e077a52c", salt: "1000", nombre: nil, apellido: nil, email: "lbob@mcbob.com", telefono: nil, tipo_usuario: nil, foto: nil, bol_activo: nil>> expected but was <nil>.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that changing the password variables doesn't update the `hashed_password` field in the database.

You probably need something like this in `Usuario`:

```
before_save :rehash

def rehash
   self.hashed_password = ??? #replace ??? with whatever your hashing logic is
end
```

Comment: check my post again, I added something